# Why there is time difference for page load in chrome dev tool and jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When I check the page loading time for a page in chrome Dev tool under network tab the system  has taken 6 seconds

When I check the page loading time for a page in chrome Dev tool under performance tab the system  has taken 8 seconds

When I check using jmeter by using blaze meter recorded file its taking 12 seconds..
Note: I have one main jsp request and 5 sub request....

- Number of User:1
- Ramp-up period:1
- Loop count:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have kept embedded resources (such as png, img, gif, js files) in the script. If so, jmeter executes them in a sequence which increases response time. Try using retrieve embedded resources check box in HTTP request defaults and check parallel downloads. By default it's value is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is due to [HTTP Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), there are so called "embedded resources": images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc, if you visit the page in the browser not the first time - the chance that the embedded resources are not downloaded each time is very high.

JMeter always establishes "clean" session, so if you want to compare it's response time with browser response time you should set up "clean" session in the browser as well, i.e. tick "Disable cache" box in the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

[image]

Check out [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for more hints on how to properly configure JMeter for producing the same network footprint as real browsers do.